# Disable all sounds while sound is playing in HTML5/jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, html5-audio, playback

I currently have buttons setup to play sounds on an activity. The main audio button plays a sentence. What I'm after is a way to have the other anchors not clickable while the main sentence plays. Here is my HTML firstly:

```
<audio id="sentence" src="../audio/m_sentence2.mp3"></audio>
<audio id="sound1" src="../../../globalResources/audio/male/hand.mp3"></audio>
<audio id="sound2" src="../../../globalResources/audio/male/foot.mp3"></audio>
<audio id="sound3" src="../../../globalResources/audio/male/nose.mp3"></audio>

<a href="#" class="audioBtn" id="audioMain"></a>
<a href="#" class="audioBtn" id="audio1"></a>
<a href="#" class="audioBtn" id="audio2"></a>
<a href="#" class="audioBtn" id="audio3"></a>
```

Now I have this jQuery written to play the sounds:

```
var sentence = $('#sentence');
var sound1 = $('#sound1');
var sound2 = $('#sound2');
var sound3 = $('#sound3');

    $("#audioMain").click(function() {
        sentence.get(0).play();
        });


    $("#audio1").click(function() {
        sound1.get(0).play();       
        });


    $("#audio2").click(function() {
        sound2.get(0).play();       
        });


    $("#audio3").click(function() {
        sound3.get(0).play();       
        });
```

Is there a way so when the sentence is playing, the other sounds can not be played? I've tried things like removeAttr but can't seem to disable the sounds. I can hide the button completely but that is not an option in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I've come up with a solution. On the sentence click function, I change the other audio button's pointer-events to none. Then wrote a bind 'ended' event function to the sentence that is playing so when it has finished playing, the other buttons become clickable again. Code below:

```
$('#sentence').bind('ended', function() {
        $('#audio1').css('pointer-events', 'auto');
        $('#audio2').css('pointer-events', 'auto');
        $('#audio3').css('pointer-events', 'auto');

        }); 


    $("#audioMain").click(function() {
        sentence.get(0).play();
        $('#audio1').css('pointer-events', 'none');
        $('#audio2').css('pointer-events', 'none');
        $('#audio3').css('pointer-events', 'none');
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Might want to make a function, but this should work.

```
var sentence = $('#sentence'),
sound1 = $('#sound1'),
sound2 = $('#sound2'),
sound3 = $('#sound3'),
sentancePlaying = false;


$("#audioMain").click(function() {
    sentence.get(0).play();
    sentancePlaying = true;
});


$("#audio1").click(function() {
    if(!sentancePlaying){ 
        sound1.get(0).play(); 
    }
});


$("#audio2").click(function() {
    if(!sentancePlaying){ 
        sound2.get(0).play();
    }
});


$("#audio3").click(function() {
    if(!sentancePlaying){ 
        sound3.get(0).play();
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the point in the right direction. This works, but the only issue is, if I play the sentence first, then I can no longer use the other sounds at all.

Comment: Isn't that what you asked to do?

Comment: Yes but I intended it so that when the sentence is playing the other sound buttons don't work, but when the sentence has finished playing, they can then be played like normal.